# MultiProvider and abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

Good day!

How can I use a Provider for MaterialApp? I have a MultiProvider and abstract class. Need to pass the auth to the LandingPage

Here is I'd like to gain:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AuthBase>(
      create: (context) => Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Bloc Test",
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo),
        home: LandingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

There is my working code:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<ToDoProvider>(
              create: (ctx) => ToDoProvider(),
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Ultimative ToDo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: myListMainColor,
            textTheme:
                  GoogleFonts.sourceSansProTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
             
            ),
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: {
              '/': (context) => LandingPage(auth: Auth()),
              OpenedToDo.routeName: (context) => OpenedToDo(),
             },
          ),
```

I have an abstract class AuthBase, but I can't mix it with ChangeNotifier. So that is a reason why I can't put a new string of code to the MultiProvider.

```
abstract class AuthBase {
  User get currentUser;
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
  Stream<User> authStateChanges();
  Future<void> singOut(BuildContext context);
  Future<User> singInWithGoogle();
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
  
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
   
  }

  @override
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
   
  }

  @override
  Future<User> singInWithGoogle() async {
  
  }

  @override
  Future<void> singOut(BuildContext context) async {
   
  }
}
```

The error is:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
> StreamBuilder Widget
>
> This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not
> include the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
>   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route,
>   then   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
>   Make sure that StreamBuilder is under your
>   MultiProvider/Provider.   This usually happen when you are
>   creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
>
>   For example, instead of:
>
>   ````
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
>       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
>       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
>     ),   }   ```
>
>   consider using `builder` like so:
>
>   ```   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
>       builder: (context) {
>         // No longer throws
>         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
>       }
>     ),   }   ```
>   ````

LandingPage:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: auth.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //* если подключился к данным
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          //* получаем данные о пользователе
          final User user = snapshot.data;

          print('~ uid is ${user?.uid}');

          if (user == null) {
            //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignInPage.routeName, arguments: auth);

            return SignInPage.create(context);
          } else {
            // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
            return HomeScreen();
          }
        }
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

SignInPage has this part of code:

```
 static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
    return Provider<SignInBloc>(
      create: (_) => SignInBloc(auth: auth),
      //* обязательно должен быть dispose
      dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      //* consumer помогает прокинуть данные в конструктор
      child: Consumer<SignInBloc>(
        child: SignInPage(),
        builder: (_, bloc, __) => SignInPage(bloc: bloc),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before moving to the abstract subject of the question I'd recommend to initiate the MultiProvider on the main folder.
Like this

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart' as provider;

void main() {
  runApp(provider.MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      provider.ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Prov1()),
      provider.ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Prov2()),
      provider.ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Prov3()),
      provider.ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Prov4()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

From this point you might be able to access at any point of your app.
Maybe using the provider you want on the classes that implement your abstract class instead of changing data directly on it. Hope I helped and got thing clear.

Comment: Igor, thanks for your answer. One thing I can't got, what is a provider? How and where declare it?

Comment: I just updated the answer, which I added the provider import, clarifying where it comes from! Hope it helps.

Comment: Igor, thanks a lot! I've just forgot about naming the import.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found how to solve it. That's pretty easy.
So in main.dart in multiProvider's section of code I should add only one string:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ToDoProvider>(
          create: (ctx) => ToDoProvider(),
        ),
        THIS CODE ==> Provider<AuthBase>.value(value: Auth()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
...
```

LandingPage.dart:

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/landingPage';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: auth.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final User user = snapshot.data;
          print('~ uid is ${user?.uid}');
            if (user == null) {
            return SignInPage.create(context);
          } else {
            // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
            return HomeScreen();
          }
        }
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And in SignInPage.dart:

```
static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
    return Provider<SignInBloc>(
      create: (_) => SignInBloc(auth: auth),
      dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      child: Consumer<SignInBloc>(
        child: SignInPage(),
        builder: (_, bloc, __) => SignInPage(bloc: bloc),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So because the AuthBase is an abstract class I can't mix it with ChangeNotifier, but I need not that because of this class is not mutable. That's why I use Provider.value(value: value).